# Conditional Probability Tables in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, math

I have this causal graph I want to create conditional probability tables for.

How can I build out a conditional probability for the variable A, if it is dependent on D, G, and Q? i.e P(A|G,Q,D)
Assuming G (Gender) is Male or Female, Qualified (Q) is Qualified or Unqualified, Department (D) is A,B,C, or D and Admit (A) is either Admitted or Rejected.

I want to do this in R.
For example the conditional probability table for D (which is dependent on G) would look like so (I'm just using arbitrary probabilities for now). How can I do this for the A variable when it's dependent on three variables?

```
A.lv <- c("A", "R")
G.lv <- c("M", "F")
Q.lv <- c("Q","U")
D.lv <- c("A","B","C","D")

D.prob <- array(c(0.2,0.5,0.4,0.1,0.8,0.5,0.6,0.9),
                dim = c(4,2),
                dimnames = list(D = D.lv, G = G.lv))

   G
D     M   F
  A 0.2 0.8
  B 0.5 0.5
  C 0.4 0.6
  D 0.1 0.9
```

[image]

Comment: How you organise it depends on what you are wanting to do with it. A 3D array might suit, or perhaps a data frame with the combinations of parent states and a column with the probabilities. But i wouldn't think you would need to roll this out yourself. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gRain/index.html might be useful

Comment: oops that should of been 4d array of course. From your example, it seems as if you have the child node on the first dimension, so this might `dim <- c(length(A.lv), length(D.lv),length(G.lv),length(Q.lv)); A.prob <- array(1:prod(dim), dim=dim , dimnames = list(A=A.lv, D=D.lv, G=G.lv, Q=Q.lv))`